# Change value from 'null' to 'undefined' in Angular Reactive Form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am currently working on a form component using `Reactive Forms` and `Angular13+.`
I have already set the form and it is working like it should, but I have a problem I can not find a solution.

I post the code for the form.

**form.component.ts:**

```
    this.myForm= this.fb.group({
      input1: new FormControl(),
      input2: new FormControl(),
      input3: new FormControl(),
      input4: new FormControl(),
      input5: new FormControl(),
    });
```

As you can see, none of the inputs are required, so the user can either fill up the input field or not.

My problem comes when I want to pass the object that returns the form (`console.log(form)`), if any of the input fields is not filled, it returns `null` but I need to return `undefined`.

Is there a way to do it?

**EDIT:**

I paste what the form returns when I do `console.log()`

```
input1: null
input2: null
input3: 'some data'
input4: null
```

When the input field is filled, it returns with the data provided, but when it is not filled, it returns null.

Comment: Can u provide a demo code on https://stackblitz.com/ ? Otherwise this will be closed

Comment: I have updated the question with that it logs. I dont think it is needed to make a stackblitz demo since it is just a clg

Comment: Why do you need it to be `undefined`?

Comment: It needs to be undefined because the object returned from the form gets sent to the backend transformed into a URL (like query params) and if the field is null, it transform it into literal string 'null', but if the field is undefined, it skips the field and doesn't append to the url.

Comment: Why you don't iterate through the keys of the final value and update the `null` to `undefined` before sending it to the BE?

Comment: Could you please explain how? I get the idea but I can't figure it out a solution

Comment: I added it as an answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by mapping the form's value before sending it to the BE, like the following:

```js
export function getMappedValue<T>(value: T): T {
  return Object.keys(value).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (value[curr] !== null) {
      acc[curr] = value[curr];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {} as T);
}

//...

// Then we can use it in the component before sending the value to BE:
const valueToBeSent = getMappedValue(this.myForm.value);
```